# Asp.net mvc 5 adding a time stamp to when things were added?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have a comment section on my website that get stored in the database. When I add a new comment I would like to see who did add it and at what date / time he / she did post it.

Not sure how I would go ahead and do that. Anyone that can push me into the right dirrection ?

I am aware I can do this.       `public DateTime Time { get; set; }`
How ever that would end up with the user entering his own date, I need to be automatic.

Here is the model I tried, which does not compile, but instead generates `Error 3 The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'System.DateTime'`:

```
public class Suggestion {
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Comment { get; set; } 
    public DateTime.Now Time { get; set; } 
}
```

And this is the error I get `Error  3   The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: add a property to your model and use `DateTime.Now()`?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer, and you didnt post any code as reference, you may get the answer you are looking for if you follow a basics on MVC CRUD operations: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Is there a datetime property in your "Comment model"? If so, just add the current system datetime (DateTime.Now)in the property value, otherwise you have to extend your Comment model to store the datetime data.

Comment: This question is likely to attract down votes and/or close votes in the way it is written now.  What is the actual question you are asking? "Anyone that can push me in the right direction?" is a yes or no answer, and *screams* that you haven't tried anything at all, or even looked anything up.  While users of the site want to help others with programming issues, they don't generally want to write full solutions....

Comment: Correct but doing that would make it so the user whom is posting enter the date? Should be automatic.

Comment: @Claies What I am trying to achive is when a user who post a comment I want to get a Time stamp. I'm aware I can do this  public DateTime Time { get; set; } but that means the user who is posting would choose the Time him self, I want that to be Automatic.

Comment: what's not automatic about `DateTime.Now()`?   Again, your question doesn't show what you have tried, or even code where this would be used that can be modified to provide a solution.

Comment: @Claies as far as I'm concern I can't use DateTime.now on a property ?

Comment: Uh what? Of course you can use `DateTime.Now()` on a property.  Now you're just trying to find a reason not to try something yourself.  `Comment.Time = DateTime.Now();  db.SaveChanges();`.  works every time.

Comment: @Claies No. This is what i've tried                                                   `public class Suggestion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public DateTime.Now Time { get; set; }
    }
}
`
Which ends up like this: ` Error 3 The type name 'Now' does not exist in the type 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: that doesn't even make sense.  if you actually posted your code in the question, then it would be easier for someone to correct your code in an answer.  The way the question was ***originally*** framed, we would have had no idea that your problem was a misunderstanding of syntax.

Comment: This is starting to look more like a question that can be answered.  Hopefully you can see the difference, and start to frame better questions in the future.  I certainly want to help, but it's much easier to help when I don't have to ask 10 questions in comments to get the real problem.

Comment: since you still seem to be having trouble, even with reasonably good answers provided, can you post the contents of your method where you save the comments to the database so you can be shown explicitly where the correct lines should be added?

Comment: @Claies I am not stuck on that certin part anymore, I did manage to get it working somewhat.

When I add a comment I can see my Time variable hold the right time and date. How ever on my view I'm requierd to enter a date / time which than over rided the variable. 

And i'm not quiet sure how to solve that, in the database it allows null, and I have not used the required atribute.

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to run automatically and every time, you should set `WhenCreated` in the the constructor. This way you don't have to remember to set it anywhere.

```
public class Suggestion 
{
  public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }
  /* other props */

  public Suggestion() 
  {
    WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

When rehydrating a `Suggestion` from a database record, `WhenCreated` will be updated by EntityFramework or whatever persistence layer you are using. This occurs after the Constructor is called, so whatever initial value you have in there won't matter. When your application is creating a new `Suggestion`, the `WhenCreated` field will be automatically set to Now.

Note: `DateTime.Now` returns the current date and time of the server's timezone. You may need to handle translation to local timezones for your users, and if that's the case, it might be good to use `DateTime.UtcNow` to get the UTC time which will be easier to localize in the future (won't double up/lose an hour during DaylightSaving moves)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Suggestion {
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public string Comment { get; set; } 
  public DateTime Time { get; set; } 
}

Suggestion s = new Suggestion();
s.Time = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:

1. When you define table to store comments in the database add new column to store datetime when row was created. Give it default value. For example in Sql Server you can use getdate() as default. Pros of this method is that you don't need to write additional C# code to set value to WhenCreated column:

.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Coments](
   [Id] [int] NULL,
   [Comment] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [WhenCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate()
)
```

2. If you want to do that in C# you can just use DateTime.Now

.

```
 public class Suggestion {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Comment { get; set; } 
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; } 
    }

    var n = new Suggestion();
    n.WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: But in order to make a new instance of the Suggestion class I have to be in another class, would that not create two tables in my DB ?

Comment: what do you mean by "to be in another class"?

Comment: @Carlssonthepirate this was a trivial example, if you already have an instance of the class which is holding the other data the user filled in, simply update the property on that instance....

Comment: it won't create two tables in db.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this

```
 public class Time
{
    private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea of what you want to do, you just don't know the way to do it.

If you have a value that you want to get set on object creation, then the perfect place to do that is in the objects default constructor.

The default constructor is called by the program every time that the object is created by a call to the new keyword.

So, back to your question, to accomplish what you want to do you simply need to do something like this:

```
public class YourClass() 
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public YourClass()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;    
    }
}
```

Happy trails!